# Because this method is running action twice

Tags: java, awt, keyboard-shortcuts, key-events

I have a method where he performs another method depending on the button clicked. 
Only he seems to be running the methods called twice, and I do not know why. Can anyone help me and explain to me why this is? Follows the source

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void eventDispatched(final AWTEvent event) {
            final KeyEvent evt = (KeyEvent) event;
            switch (evt.getKeyCode()) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_F1: { 
                    //F1
                    doSomething(); // this method is running twice

                    break;
                }
                case KeyEvent.VK_F2: {
                    //F2
                    doSomething();
                    break;
                }
                }, AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
```

Thanks

Comment: Look at the answer from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864297/onkey-event-dispatched-twice-when-i-type-some-text-into-a-textbox-how-to-preven

Comment: @mdewitt That won't help. He's checking o emsure the correct key is pressed.

Comment: @Stendika But he might be getting an event from the down action and the up from the correct key press. Both would have the correct key code.

Comment: I got it, and how can I check to only run in the KeyPress and not in keyrelease?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving an event for KEY_PRESSED and KEY_RELEASED.

You need to check if, in addition to the `KeyEvent` having the correct KeyCode you want to make sure it is the correct action, ie KEY_PRESSSED. One way to fix this is add a check for the action before you go into your switch statement.

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void eventDispatched(final AWTEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED)
        {
            final KeyEvent evt = (KeyEvent) event;
            switch(event.getKeyCode()){
                 //switch statement code
            }
        }   
    }, AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
```

Another thing you could do is create a `KeyEventDispatcher` and add it to the `KeyboardFocusManager` like this:

```
    //create KeyEventDispatcher myKeyEventDispatcher
    KeyboardFocusManager focusManager = KeyboardFocusManager.
            getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager(); 
    focusManager.addKeyEventDispatcher(myKeyEventDispatcher);
```

That way you will only get key event and you can dispatch them yourself

Comment: You're welcome. If one of the answers helped you, you can accept it so this is no longer an unanswered question.

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to be that both the key-press and key-released methods are triggering the event. I would recommend using `java.awt.event.KeyListener`, which has separate event handlers for the press and release events.